# How to pytest local variable like dict inside function?

Tags: python, pytest

For example I have a function like below:

```
def func(val):
    dict = {}
    # some logic to fill in dict
    dict['a'] = val
```

Then how can I pytest the the contents of dict? Is it possible?

Comment: what pattern would you check? is it the same in every case?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually replace the `dict` constructor, for the tested module, if you can change your code slightly. Suppose that your module name is `my_module.py` and you can make the following changes:

1. Initialize the dictionary using `dict()` instead of `{}`
2. Rename `dict` into `my_dict` (or any other name so it doesn't shadows the builtin `dict()`)

`my_module.py` would look like so:

```
def func(val):
    my_dict = dict()  # instead of dict = {}
    # some logic to fill in dict
    my_dict['a'] = val
```

Then, in your test, override the `dict` constructor which creates new dictionaries and return your dictionary that you can assert later on:

```
from my_module import func


def test_func(mocker):
    my_replaced_dict = {}
    mocker.patch("my_module.dict", return_value=my_replaced_dict)
    func(20)
    assert my_replaced_dict['a'] == 20  # the assert works since func uses our variable
```